# Error including <omp.h> (c++)

Tags: c++, openmp

Ok, so I'm trying to parallelize some C++ code using OpenMP, but I keep getting this weird error. The compiler finds the library and everything, but it gives me an error in side the library itself. It says:

```
In function 'void set_num_threads(int)':
error: expected primary-initialization before ',' token
```

The error occurs in this line:

```
extern void omp_set_num_threads (int) __GOMP_NOTHROW;
```

... but it also gives an error for almost every other function the file defines. I figure there's something wrong with my compiler, but I don't know what it could be or how to fix it. Help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

*UPDATE* I tried running the code on an online compiler and I got the same error, so I have no idea what's wrong.

Ok, so including a random number generator I got from my professor seems to cause the problem. This is the code for its .h file.

```
#ifndef _NR3_H_
#define _NR3_H_

//#define _CHECKBOUNDS_ 1
//#define _USESTDVECTOR_ 1
//#define _USENRERRORCLASS_ 1
//#define _TURNONFPES_ 1

// all the system #include's we'll ever need
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

// macro-like inline functions

template<class T>
inline T SQR(const T a) {return a*a;}

template<class T>
inline const T &MAX(const T &a, const T &b)
        {return b > a ? (b) : (a);}

inline float MAX(const double &a, const float &b)
        {return b > a ? (b) : float(a);}

inline float MAX(const float &a, const double &b)
        {return b > a ? float(b) : (a);}

template<class T>
inline const T &MIN(const T &a, const T &b)
        {return b < a ? (b) : (a);}

inline float MIN(const double &a, const float &b)
        {return b < a ? (b) : float(a);}

inline float MIN(const float &a, const double &b)
        {return b < a ? float(b) : (a);}

template<class T>
inline T SIGN(const T &a, const T &b)
    {return b >= 0 ? (a >= 0 ? a : -a) : (a >= 0 ? -a : a);}

inline float SIGN(const float &a, const double &b)
    {return b >= 0 ? (a >= 0 ? a : -a) : (a >= 0 ? -a : a);}

inline float SIGN(const double &a, const float &b)
    {return (float)(b >= 0 ? (a >= 0 ? a : -a) : (a >= 0 ? -a : a));}

template<class T>
inline void SWAP(T &a, T &b)
    {T dum=a; a=b; b=dum;}

// exception handling

#ifndef _USENRERRORCLASS_
#define throw(message) \
{printf("ERROR: %s\n     in file %s at line %d\n", message,__FILE__,__LINE__); throw(1);}
#else
struct NRerror {
    char *message;
    char *file;
    int line;
    NRerror(char *m, char *f, int l) : message(m), file(f), line(l) {}
};
#define throw(message) throw(NRerror(message,__FILE__,__LINE__));
void NRcatch(NRerror err) {
    printf("ERROR: %s\n     in file %s at line %d\n",
        err.message, err.file, err.line);
    exit(1);
}
#endif

// usage example:
//
//  try {
//      somebadroutine();
//  }
//  catch(NRerror s) {NRcatch(s);}
//
// (You can of course substitute any other catch body for NRcatch(s).)


// Vector and Matrix Classes

#ifdef _USESTDVECTOR_
#define NRvector vector
#else

template <class T>
class NRvector {
private:
    int nn; // size of array. upper index is nn-1
    T *v;
public:
    NRvector();
    explicit NRvector(int n);       // Zero-based array
    NRvector(int n, const T &a);    //initialize to constant value
    NRvector(int n, const T *a);    // Initialize to array
    NRvector(const NRvector &rhs);  // Copy constructor
    NRvector & operator=(const NRvector &rhs);  //assignment
    typedef T value_type; // make T available externally
    inline T & operator[](const int i); //i'th element
    inline const T & operator[](const int i) const;
    inline int size() const;
    void resize(int newn); // resize (contents not preserved)
    void assign(int newn, const T &a); // resize and assign a constant value
    ~NRvector();
};

// NRvector definitions

template <class T>
NRvector<T>::NRvector() : nn(0), v(NULL) {}

template <class T>
NRvector<T>::NRvector(int n) : nn(n), v(n>0 ? new T[n] : NULL) {}

template <class T>
NRvector<T>::NRvector(int n, const T& a) : nn(n), v(n>0 ? new T[n] : NULL)
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) v[i] = a;
}

template <class T>
NRvector<T>::NRvector(int n, const T *a) : nn(n), v(n>0 ? new T[n] : NULL)
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) v[i] = *a++;
}

template <class T>
NRvector<T>::NRvector(const NRvector<T> &rhs) : nn(rhs.nn), v(nn>0 ? new T[nn] : NULL)
{
    for(int i=0; i<nn; i++) v[i] = rhs[i];
}

template <class T>
NRvector<T> & NRvector<T>::operator=(const NRvector<T> &rhs)
// postcondition: normal assignment via copying has been performed;
//      if vector and rhs were different sizes, vector
//      has been resized to match the size of rhs
{
    if (this != &rhs)
    {
        if (nn != rhs.nn) {
            if (v != NULL) delete [] (v);
            nn=rhs.nn;
            v= nn>0 ? new T[nn] : NULL;
        }
        for (int i=0; i<nn; i++)
            v[i]=rhs[i];
    }
    return *this;
}

template <class T>
inline T & NRvector<T>::operator[](const int i) //subscripting
{
#ifdef _CHECKBOUNDS_
if (i<0 || i>=nn) {
    throw("NRvector subscript out of bounds");
}
#endif
    return v[i];
}

template <class T>
inline const T & NRvector<T>::operator[](const int i) const //subscripting
{
#ifdef _CHECKBOUNDS_
if (i<0 || i>=nn) {
    throw("NRvector subscript out of bounds");
}
#endif
    return v[i];
}

template <class T>
inline int NRvector<T>::size() const
{
    return nn;
}

template <class T>
void NRvector<T>::resize(int newn)
{
    if (newn != nn) {
        if (v != NULL) delete[] (v);
        nn = newn;
        v = nn > 0 ? new T[nn] : NULL;
    }
}

template <class T>
void NRvector<T>::assign(int newn, const T& a)
{
    if (newn != nn) {
        if (v != NULL) delete[] (v);
        nn = newn;
        v = nn > 0 ? new T[nn] : NULL;
    }
    for (int i=0;i<nn;i++) v[i] = a;
}

template <class T>
NRvector<T>::~NRvector()
{
    if (v != NULL) delete[] (v);
}

// end of NRvector definitions

#endif //ifdef _USESTDVECTOR_

template <class T>
class NRmatrix {
private:
    int nn;
    int mm;
    T **v;
public:
    NRmatrix();
    NRmatrix(int n, int m);         // Zero-based array
    NRmatrix(int n, int m, const T &a); //Initialize to constant
    NRmatrix(int n, int m, const T *a); // Initialize to array
    NRmatrix(const NRmatrix &rhs);      // Copy constructor
    NRmatrix & operator=(const NRmatrix &rhs);  //assignment
    typedef T value_type; // make T available externally
    inline T* operator[](const int i);  //subscripting: pointer to row i
    inline const T* operator[](const int i) const;
    inline int nrows() const;
    inline int ncols() const;
    void resize(int newn, int newm); // resize (contents not preserved)
    void assign(int newn, int newm, const T &a); // resize and assign a constant value
    ~NRmatrix();
};

template <class T>
NRmatrix<T>::NRmatrix() : nn(0), mm(0), v(NULL) {}

template <class T>
NRmatrix<T>::NRmatrix(int n, int m) : nn(n), mm(m), v(n>0 ? new T*[n] : NULL)
{
    int i,nel=m*n;
    if (v) v[0] = nel>0 ? new T[nel] : NULL;
    for (i=1;i<n;i++) v[i] = v[i-1] + m;
}

template <class T>
NRmatrix<T>::NRmatrix(int n, int m, const T &a) : nn(n), mm(m), v(n>0 ? new T*[n] : NULL)
{
    int i,j,nel=m*n;
    if (v) v[0] = nel>0 ? new T[nel] : NULL;
    for (i=1; i< n; i++) v[i] = v[i-1] + m;
    for (i=0; i< n; i++) for (j=0; j<m; j++) v[i][j] = a;
}

template <class T>
NRmatrix<T>::NRmatrix(int n, int m, const T *a) : nn(n), mm(m), v(n>0 ? new T*[n] : NULL)
{
    int i,j,nel=m*n;
    if (v) v[0] = nel>0 ? new T[nel] : NULL;
    for (i=1; i< n; i++) v[i] = v[i-1] + m;
    for (i=0; i< n; i++) for (j=0; j<m; j++) v[i][j] = *a++;
}

template <class T>
NRmatrix<T>::NRmatrix(const NRmatrix &rhs) : nn(rhs.nn), mm(rhs.mm), v(nn>0 ? new T*[nn] : NULL)
{
    int i,j,nel=mm*nn;
    if (v) v[0] = nel>0 ? new T[nel] : NULL;
    for (i=1; i< nn; i++) v[i] = v[i-1] + mm;
    for (i=0; i< nn; i++) for (j=0; j<mm; j++) v[i][j] = rhs[i][j];
}

template <class T>
NRmatrix<T> & NRmatrix<T>::operator=(const NRmatrix<T> &rhs)
// postcondition: normal assignment via copying has been performed;
//      if matrix and rhs were different sizes, matrix
//      has been resized to match the size of rhs
{
    if (this != &rhs) {
        int i,j,nel;
        if (nn != rhs.nn || mm != rhs.mm) {
            if (v != NULL) {
                delete[] (v[0]);
                delete[] (v);
            }
            nn=rhs.nn;
            mm=rhs.mm;
            v = nn>0 ? new T*[nn] : NULL;
            nel = mm*nn;
            if (v) v[0] = nel>0 ? new T[nel] : NULL;
            for (i=1; i< nn; i++) v[i] = v[i-1] + mm;
        }
        for (i=0; i< nn; i++) for (j=0; j<mm; j++) v[i][j] = rhs[i][j];
    }
    return *this;
}

template <class T>
inline T* NRmatrix<T>::operator[](const int i)  //subscripting: pointer to row i
{
#ifdef _CHECKBOUNDS_
if (i<0 || i>=nn) {
    throw("NRmatrix subscript out of bounds");
}
#endif
    return v[i];
}

template <class T>
inline const T* NRmatrix<T>::operator[](const int i) const
{
#ifdef _CHECKBOUNDS_
if (i<0 || i>=nn) {
    throw("NRmatrix subscript out of bounds");
}
#endif
    return v[i];
}

template <class T>
inline int NRmatrix<T>::nrows() const
{
    return nn;
}

template <class T>
inline int NRmatrix<T>::ncols() const
{
    return mm;
}

template <class T>
void NRmatrix<T>::resize(int newn, int newm)
{
    int i,nel;
    if (newn != nn || newm != mm) {
        if (v != NULL) {
            delete[] (v[0]);
            delete[] (v);
        }
        nn = newn;
        mm = newm;
        v = nn>0 ? new T*[nn] : NULL;
        nel = mm*nn;
        if (v) v[0] = nel>0 ? new T[nel] : NULL;
        for (i=1; i< nn; i++) v[i] = v[i-1] + mm;
    }
}

template <class T>
void NRmatrix<T>::assign(int newn, int newm, const T& a)
{
    int i,j,nel;
    if (newn != nn || newm != mm) {
        if (v != NULL) {
            delete[] (v[0]);
            delete[] (v);
        }
        nn = newn;
        mm = newm;
        v = nn>0 ? new T*[nn] : NULL;
        nel = mm*nn;
        if (v) v[0] = nel>0 ? new T[nel] : NULL;
        for (i=1; i< nn; i++) v[i] = v[i-1] + mm;
    }
    for (i=0; i< nn; i++) for (j=0; j<mm; j++) v[i][j] = a;
}

template <class T>
NRmatrix<T>::~NRmatrix()
{
    if (v != NULL) {
        delete[] (v[0]);
        delete[] (v);
    }
}

template <class T>
class NRMat3d {
private:
    int nn;
    int mm;
    int kk;
    T ***v;
public:
    NRMat3d();
    NRMat3d(int n, int m, int k);
    inline T** operator[](const int i); //subscripting: pointer to row i
    inline const T* const * operator[](const int i) const;
    inline int dim1() const;
    inline int dim2() const;
    inline int dim3() const;
    ~NRMat3d();
};

template <class T>
NRMat3d<T>::NRMat3d(): nn(0), mm(0), kk(0), v(NULL) {}

template <class T>
NRMat3d<T>::NRMat3d(int n, int m, int k) : nn(n), mm(m), kk(k), v(new T**[n])
{
    int i,j;
    v[0] = new T*[n*m];
    v[0][0] = new T[n*m*k];
    for(j=1; j<m; j++) v[0][j] = v[0][j-1] + k;
    for(i=1; i<n; i++) {
        v[i] = v[i-1] + m;
        v[i][0] = v[i-1][0] + m*k;
        for(j=1; j<m; j++) v[i][j] = v[i][j-1] + k;
    }
}

template <class T>
inline T** NRMat3d<T>::operator[](const int i) //subscripting: pointer to row i
{
    return v[i];
}

template <class T>
inline const T* const * NRMat3d<T>::operator[](const int i) const
{
    return v[i];
}

template <class T>
inline int NRMat3d<T>::dim1() const
{
    return nn;
}

template <class T>
inline int NRMat3d<T>::dim2() const
{
    return mm;
}

template <class T>
inline int NRMat3d<T>::dim3() const
{
    return kk;
}

template <class T>
NRMat3d<T>::~NRMat3d()
{
    if (v != NULL) {
        delete[] (v[0][0]);
        delete[] (v[0]);
        delete[] (v);
    }
}


// basic type names (redefine if your bit lengths don't match)

typedef int Int; // 32 bit integer
typedef unsigned int Uint;

#ifdef _MSC_VER
typedef __int64 Llong; // 64 bit integer
typedef unsigned __int64 Ullong;
#else
typedef long long int Llong; // 64 bit integer
typedef unsigned long long int Ullong;
#endif

typedef char Char; // 8 bit integer
typedef unsigned char Uchar;

typedef double Doub; // default floating type
typedef long double Ldoub;

typedef complex<double> Complex; // default complex type

typedef bool Bool;

// NaN: uncomment one of the following 3 methods of defining a global NaN
// you can test by verifying that (NaN != NaN) is true

static const Doub NaN = numeric_limits<Doub>::quiet_NaN();

//Uint proto_nan[2]={0xffffffff, 0x7fffffff};
//double NaN = *( double* )proto_nan;

//Doub NaN = sqrt(-1.);

// vector types

typedef const NRvector<Int> VecInt_I;
typedef NRvector<Int> VecInt, VecInt_O, VecInt_IO;

typedef const NRvector<Uint> VecUint_I;
typedef NRvector<Uint> VecUint, VecUint_O, VecUint_IO;

typedef const NRvector<Llong> VecLlong_I;
typedef NRvector<Llong> VecLlong, VecLlong_O, VecLlong_IO;

typedef const NRvector<Ullong> VecUllong_I;
typedef NRvector<Ullong> VecUllong, VecUllong_O, VecUllong_IO;

typedef const NRvector<Char> VecChar_I;
typedef NRvector<Char> VecChar, VecChar_O, VecChar_IO;

typedef const NRvector<Char*> VecCharp_I;
typedef NRvector<Char*> VecCharp, VecCharp_O, VecCharp_IO;

typedef const NRvector<Uchar> VecUchar_I;
typedef NRvector<Uchar> VecUchar, VecUchar_O, VecUchar_IO;

typedef const NRvector<Doub> VecDoub_I;
typedef NRvector<Doub> VecDoub, VecDoub_O, VecDoub_IO;

typedef const NRvector<Doub*> VecDoubp_I;
typedef NRvector<Doub*> VecDoubp, VecDoubp_O, VecDoubp_IO;

typedef const NRvector<Complex> VecComplex_I;
typedef NRvector<Complex> VecComplex, VecComplex_O, VecComplex_IO;

typedef const NRvector<Bool> VecBool_I;
typedef NRvector<Bool> VecBool, VecBool_O, VecBool_IO;

// matrix types

typedef const NRmatrix<Int> MatInt_I;
typedef NRmatrix<Int> MatInt, MatInt_O, MatInt_IO;

typedef const NRmatrix<Uint> MatUint_I;
typedef NRmatrix<Uint> MatUint, MatUint_O, MatUint_IO;

typedef const NRmatrix<Llong> MatLlong_I;
typedef NRmatrix<Llong> MatLlong, MatLlong_O, MatLlong_IO;

typedef const NRmatrix<Ullong> MatUllong_I;
typedef NRmatrix<Ullong> MatUllong, MatUllong_O, MatUllong_IO;

typedef const NRmatrix<Char> MatChar_I;
typedef NRmatrix<Char> MatChar, MatChar_O, MatChar_IO;

typedef const NRmatrix<Uchar> MatUchar_I;
typedef NRmatrix<Uchar> MatUchar, MatUchar_O, MatUchar_IO;

typedef const NRmatrix<Doub> MatDoub_I;
typedef NRmatrix<Doub> MatDoub, MatDoub_O, MatDoub_IO;

typedef const NRmatrix<Bool> MatBool_I;
typedef NRmatrix<Bool> MatBool, MatBool_O, MatBool_IO;

// 3D matrix types

typedef const NRMat3d<Doub> Mat3DDoub_I;
typedef NRMat3d<Doub> Mat3DDoub, Mat3DDoub_O, Mat3DDoub_IO;

// Floating Point Exceptions for Microsoft compilers

#ifdef _TURNONFPES_
#ifdef _MSC_VER
struct turn_on_floating_exceptions {
    turn_on_floating_exceptions() {
        int cw = _controlfp( 0, 0 );
        cw &=~(EM_INVALID | EM_OVERFLOW | EM_ZERODIVIDE );
        _controlfp( cw, MCW_EM );
    }
};
turn_on_floating_exceptions yes_turn_on_floating_exceptions;
#endif /* _MSC_VER */
#endif /* _TURNONFPES */

#endif /* _NR3_H_ */





/*This is the ran.h routine provided by NR page 342.  It creates a uniform random deviate between 0 and 1,
  and it is useful for either 64 or 32 bit machines */
struct Ran
{
  Ullong u, v, w;
  Ran(Ullong j) : v(4101842887655102017LL), w(1)
  {
    u = j ^ v; int64();
    v = u; int64();
    w = v; int64();
  }
  inline Ullong int64()
  {
    u = u * 2862933555777941757LL + 7046029254386353087LL;
    v ^= v >> 17; v ^= v << 31; v ^= v >> 8;
    w = 4294957665U * (w & 0xffffffff) + (w >> 32);
    Ullong x = u ^ (u << 21); x ^= x >> 35; x ^= x << 4;
    return (x+v) ^ w;
  }
  inline Doub doub() {return 5.42101086242752217E-20 * int64(); }
  inline Uint int32() { return (Uint)int64();}
};



struct Normaldev : Ran {
    Doub mu, sig;
    Normaldev(Doub mmu, Doub ssig, Ullong i)
    : Ran(i), mu(mmu), sig (ssig){}
    Doub dev()
    {
        Doub u,v,x,y,q;
        do{
            u = doub();
            v = 1.7156*(doub() - 0.5);
            x = u - 0.449871;
            y = abs(v) + 0.386595;
            q = SQR(x) + y * (0.19600*y - 0.25472*x);
        } while (q > 0.27597 && (q > 0.27846 || SQR(v) > -4.*log(u)*SQR(u)));
        return mu + sig*v/u;
    }
};
```

*Other Update* Apparently if I put 'include omp.h' before 'include "nr3.h"' it compiles(I guess because omp compiles before throw is redefined as a macro). Thank you so much for your help everyone.

Comment: Do you have weird macros defined? `omp_set_num_threads` isn't a macro is it?

Comment: Can you show us the code around your include statement? It's possible the syntax error occurs before the include.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong is the macro "__GOMP_NOTHROW" is undefined.

POSSIBLE WORKAROUND: Add `-D__GOMP_NOTHROW` to your compile switches.  For example, add it to "CFLAGS" at the top of your Makefile, or "define macro" in your IDE.

Here's the definition from one version of omp.h:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
# define __GOMP_NOTHROW throw ()
#else
# define __GOMP_NOTHROW __attribute__((__nothrow__))
#endif
```

Comment: The error is showing up in the library, though. I know the library is working, and __GOMP_NOTHROW is defined earlier in the file. There's something wrong with how I'm including the library.

Comment: So your professor gave you some weird "nr3.h" header that redefines "throw" as a macro?  Charming ;)  Q: Out of curiousity, what compiler/compiler version/platform are you on?

Answer (score 0):

Compile your program with the option (for g++)

```
-fopenmp
```

Or the openmp flag compatible with your compiler.